# How to add Mouse event to custom template ListBox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox

Sorry if this is too primitive but I searched and found nothing to solve my problem.

I have this Control Template for my list box item:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="outerBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="innerBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                                    <Label x:Name="iconi" Content="#" Foreground="Red"/>
                                                                          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding YearClass}" ContentSource="Binding YearClass" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                                </StackPanel>
                                <Border x:Name="NumBorder" MinWidth="20" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="#8395bb" CornerRadius="10" >
                                    <Label x:Name="BookNum" Content="{Binding Path=NumbOfBook}" Foreground="#ffffff" FontSize="10" />
                                </Border>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
```

And this code make data source for the list box:

```
  public void fill_lib()
    {
        List<YearBook> yeartitles = new List<YearBook>();
        yeartitles.Add(new YearBook() { xContent ="One", YearClass = "first year", NumbOfBook = 17, selectlink = "openWind" });
        yeartitles.Add(new YearBook() { xContent = "Two", YearClass = "second year", NumbOfBook = 5, selectlink = "showItem" });
        yeartitles.Add(new YearBook() { xContent = "three", YearClass = "third year", NumbOfBook = 14, selectlink = "dataTemp" });

        middleone.ItemsSource = yeartitles;
    }
```

My question is how can I Add mouse click event or selected event two my list items?

Comment: you don't need to override ListBoxItem.Template to display custom fields. Just use ItemTemplate property of ListBox. ControlTemplate with bindings to DataContext (like `"{Binding Path=NumbOfBook}"`) is hardly reusable

Comment: which mouse event and for what purpose you want to have? consider using SelectedItem property with SelectedItemChanged event or consider InputBindings

Comment: Sorry I edited my last line of question about the event i want. selected or mouse click event

Comment: ListBoxItem has [Selected event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.selectedevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into event handlers that can handle your mouseclick.  Here's some sample code that will react whenever you change the selected index in your ListBox.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override ListBoxItem Template to display custom fields. By useing ItemTemplate property of ListBox you can get what you want. something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mainbox" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="Green" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BaseName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"   />
                        <Border CornerRadius="12" Background="#FFB05656" MinWidth="15">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BaseBookCount}" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In this case you have access to the events of ListBox and if you want to retrieve data of ListBoxItem you could use this code:

```
 private void mylst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //recive item data as user type (that I defined)
            var text = (mylst.SelectedItem as User);
            Console.WriteLine(text.Name.ToString()+ " "+ text.Mail.ToString());
        }
```